# jdbc equivalent to libpq "hostaddr" connection string parameter

Tags: postgresql

Is there an equivalent to libpq's [hostaddr](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) parameter in the JDBC connection string? I want to connect via a local TCP proxy (on 127.0.0.1), but use `ssl=verify-full` with the CA bundle of the remote Postgres instance.

It doesn't seem to be obvious how to do this in the JDBC driver without some sort of class overloading of the HostVerifier?  Anyone tried this before?

Comment: `hostaddr` in libpq should be the ip address of the server that hosts postgresql. What error message do you get? What is a TCP proxy? Is it someting like a forwarding server? i.e., you connect your socket to localhost, but all data will be forwarded to a different one?

Comment: TCP proxy forwarding as in

    `% ssh -fNT -L 15432:remotepg.theirs.com:5432 bastion.mine.com`

which sets up a port listening on my local host (127.0.0.1) on 15432, but forwards it via bastion.mine.com to remotepg.theirs.com on 5432.  

Then I can do the following in psql:  

    `% psql "postgres:/me@remotepg.theirs.com:15432/mydb?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=ca-bundle.pem&hostaddr=127.0.0.1"`

This checks the certificate sent from remotepg.theirs.com is issued via the `ca-bunde.pem` and also matches `remotepg.theirs.com`, even though I connected to localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your proxy is just a TCP forwarder, like iptables DNAT, your postgresql certificate has to include a SubjectAlternativeNames with the IP address you connect to (the proxy address).
Otherwise, if your proxy decode SSL and creates a different connection to postgresql, then the same change should be made to the proxy server.

Comment: So there's no way to do the equivalent of `% psql "postgres:/me@remotepg.theirs.com:15432/mydb?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=ca-bundle.pem&hostaddr=127.0.0.1"` in the JDBC Postgres driver?

Comment: I just read the documentation once again and I do believe that the server address is always the one specified as the host part in the URL. There is no equivalent parameter.